# how to prevent "shift+greater than" being typed in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement where I have to prevent user from typing in shift+greater than in textbox.
I looked up in the ascii key code chart.I could see no ascii key for shift+greater than combination which renders ">" on the UI.

This is the code that i have tried so far.

```
   $scope.isValidControlInputInteger = function (event) {
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
    if (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57 && event.shiftKey) { // decimal numbers
        return true;
    } else if (keyCode >= 96 && keyCode <= 105) { // numerical pad
        return true;
    } else if (keyCode == 46 || keyCode == 8) { // delete and backspace
        return true;
    } else if (keyCode == 37 || keyCode == 39) { // arrow keys
        return true;
    }
    else if (keyCode == 9) {        // tab key
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: "prevent user from typing in shift+greater than in textbox" - why? Is it because your server isn't secured against trivial HTML injection attacks?

Comment: Should be straight forward if you use the keycode `62` and the correct event -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/dnz0fgft/

Comment: (also, don't forget keyboards where > is typed without the shift key - mainly virtual ones - and various non-keyboard ways to input text such as the system clipboard)

Comment: Not the way I'd do it, @sameer; I would still be able to copy+paste `>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple workaround that works better than checking for keyup is to just remove all instances of `>` upon changing the contents of the input field.

```js
$("#field").on("keyup", function(e) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\>/g, ""))
});
```

---

#### **[Here's a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/j0bz8nLt/)**